# Filter child entity LINQ methods

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, linq-to-entities, ria

Consider the following query :

```
  IQueryable<Employee> ret = this.ObjectContext.Employees
            .Include("EmployeeInformation")
            .Include("LatestInformation")
            .Where(emp => emp.idJobTitle == 1 && emp.idCrtLoc == 1);
```

The `Employees` entity doesn't have a navigation property to `LatestInformation`'s entity(So I can't directly access the other entity) but the `LatestInformation` does have a navigation property to the Employees entity.

How can I filter the LatestInformation entity of this query?

The expected query should look like this :

```
ret = ret.Where(r=> LatestInformation.Where(li => li.year == 2015)); // Ofcourse this piece of code is wrong.
```

So , the question was how to filter the `LatestInformation` entity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no navigation property from `Employee` to `LatestInformation`, query it the other way around. Something like:

```
var ret = this.ObjectContext.LatestInfomration
    .Where(i => i.Employee != null && i.year == 2015)
    .Select(i => i.Employee)
    .Where(emp => emp.idJobTitle == 1 && emp.idCrtLoc == 1);
```

---

**Edited to match OP comment below:**

```
// Extract needed data:
var employeeIdListWithInfo = this.ObjectContext.LatestInfomration
    .Where(i => i.Employee != null)
    .Select(i => i.Employee.Id)
    .ToList();

// Build the query (not executed yet)
var employeeWithInformation = this.ObjectContext.LatestInfomration
    .Where(i => i.Employee != null && i.year == 2015)
    .Select(i => i.Employee)
    .Where(emp => emp.idJobTitle == 1 && emp.idCrtLoc == 1);

var lonelyEmployees = this.ObjectContext.Employee
    .Where(emp => !employeeIdListWithInfo.Contains(emp.Id));

var ret = employeeWithInformation.Union(lonelyEmployees);
```

Comment: I know but the purpose of the query is to fetch the data from the Employees along the other data that may or may not exist.

Comment: Actually if I'm using this approach I should somehow make the query as a LEFT JOIN which would suit my needs .. am I right?

Comment: @Alex Do you mean that you also want the `Employee` that do not have any `LastInformation` entry?

Comment: @Alex I updated my answer. You should do the same with your question.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by navigation property?

If its some unique id then you could use

```
List<int> latest = this.ObjectContext.LatestInformation.Select(lat=> lat.someid).ToList();

ret = ret.Where(r=> latest.Contains(ret.id)).Where(emp => emp.idJobTitle == 1 && emp.idCrtLoc == 1);
```